# Problem installing certificates with letsencrypt

Tags: apache2, webserver, ssl, letsencrypt

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 Server.

I have several virtual host configured. I installed letsencrypt with `sudo apt-get install letsencrypt` and installed a few certificates for specific domains with the command `sudo letsencrypt --apache -d domain.name`.

Today I configured a new virtual host with the same configuration of the ssl virtual hosts on the machine and tried to run the command to install the certificate but I got the following message `Client does not support any combination of challenges that will satisfy the CA.`

So I wasn't able to install the certificate for the new domain. Any suggestion?

Comment: I also installed certbot from PPA and launched the command line `sudo certbot --apache -d domain.name`, but I'm still receiving the same message. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Let's Encrypt has currently disabled TLS-SNI-01 challenge due to some security issue. The temporary workaround according to Let's Encrypt is provided in the link below (this worked for me).

```
sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path <path to served directory> --installer apache -d domain
```

For more details please check:

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/solution-client-with-the-currently-selected-authenticator-does-not-support-any-combination-of-challenges-that-will-satisfy-the-ca/49983

Comment: `sudo: certbot: command not found`. I've checked the page at the address https://letsencrypt.status.io/ and now everything seems to be ok, but also with my method, I keep on receiving the same error.

Comment: certbot is the new name for the letsencrypt command